# i have problem with extra spaces error in react vscode

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, eslint

hy, i have problems with with reactjs and react-native pages in vscode.
example = "expected indentation of 10 spaces but found 20".
i installed eslint and prettier and it's didnt
that's my .eslintrc:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2020": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "airbnb"
    ],
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 11,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [2, "tab", { "SwitchCase": 1, "VariableDeclarator": 1 }],
        "no-tabs": 0,
        "react/prop-types": 0,
        "react/jsx-indent": [2, "tab"],
        "react/jsx-indent-props": [2, "tab"],
    }
}
```

but i think there is a problem in my setting.json

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Files" > "Preferences" > "Settings" then search "indent".
Search for "tab size" and make it 4.
Search for "auto indent" and select "full".

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: the tab size is 4 and the auto indent is full, i didnt change that. what need to be the  "editor.defaultFormatter":???

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, look at the bottom right side of Vscode and make sure you have Javascript as defined language for the current project or tab. If not, click on what you have there and match it the right programming language to **.js** file extension. I hope that could help someone.

[look at the bottom right of your vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnEff.png)